# Different style for each radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

i am trying to stylise these 3 radio buttons for my website, easy enough, except i need them all to look different. For instance one has the option paypal, the other alertpay and the other check, each with a different image. This is proving tough as i am trying many different tutorials, all showing me how to just change it for one, but then not be able to for the others.

This is one of the tutorials i am trying to follow - http://screwdefaultbuttons.com/

Can anyone give me any ideas or links to somewhere that could help me. Thanks

Comment: Read up on CSS.  You should be able to just give each button a specific class and reference them individually rather than holistically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, define your classes in the css with some fancy formatting, like:

```
.button1 { 
   width: 19px;
   height: 25px;
   padding: 0 5px 0 0;
   background: url(checkbox.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.button2 {
   width: 19px;
   height: 25px;
   padding: 0 5px 0 0;
   background: url(somethingelse.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

And then put the classes in the html, like:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" class="button1" />
```

Comment: ok, great, but how would i get it to change to a different image, if the user selects one of the buttons?

Comment: .button1:active {background: url(differentimage.jpg) no-repeat;
}

Comment: Hi, i tried what you mentioned, but when i go to test it, for some reason there is no image appearing, just a default radio button. I have checked the image and it is correct, any ideas?

Comment: Hi, i checked the path and it is correct, still no image showing

Comment: you should make sure to add the background position in there if you are using shorthand i.e. background:url(something.jpg) top left no-repeat;

Answer (score -3):

You should call `screwDefaultButtons` individually to set different images on each e.g.

```
$('#radio1').screwDefaultButtons({ 
         checked: "url(images/radio_Checked1.jpg)",
         unchecked: "url(images/radio_Unchecked1.jpg)",
         width:    85,
         height:   85
});

$('#radio2').screwDefaultButtons({
         checked: "url(images/radio_Checked2.jpg)",
         unchecked: "url(images/radio_Unchecked2.jpg)",
         width:    85,
         height:   85
});
```

BTW that 'screwDefaultButtons' link is not a tutorial but usage of that jQuery plugin for custom buttons.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, i tried what you asked but its not really working, i did what you said but what i get is it just displaying the check image 3 times and then when you select it they all change to the paypal selected image, any ideas? Thanks for your help

Comment: are you sure you are using correct images and correct css selector in `$('#radio1')`

Comment: Hi, yes i have checked that all images are correct, now what happens is they all appear as the unchecked check image, then if you click the paypal one it changes to checked paypal, alertpay - checked alertpay etc... But they are all selected, and i thought radio buttons you could only select one?

Comment: -1 for not linking to the [jQuery plugin](http://screwdefaultbuttons.com/). Another -1 if I could for using jQuery to answer this question when CSS is enough.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine I did not link or suggested the plugin OP has linked it and mentioned it in his question, read that first, also I have answered the OP's specific question about that plugin

Comment: Oh, my bad for the first -1 I gave then. The second is still valid tho.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine op had problem using that plugin and I answered that how to use it on different radio buttons, both -1 are not valid :) and who has given the third one ?

Comment: Hi, sorry but i am still getting errors with your answer, i have checked, and double checked everything, but it still displays the third button (check) in all 3 buttons, and allows me to select all the buttons, when it should just allow one.